# How to construct a timedelta object from a simple string

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I'm writing a function that needs to parse string to a `timedelta`. The user must enter something like `"32m"` or `"2h32m"`, or even `"4:13"` or `"5hr34m56s"`... Is there a library or something that has this sort of thing already implemented?

Comment: For people just looking to construct a timedelta object of `d` days, `h` hours, `m` minutes and `s` seconds using one line (after importing `datetime`): `datetime.timedelta(days = d, hours = h, minutes=m, seconds=s)`.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

For the first format (`5hr34m56s`), you should parse using regular expressions

Here is re-based solution:

```
import re
from datetime import timedelta


regex = re.compile(r'((?P<hours>\d+?)hr)?((?P<minutes>\d+?)m)?((?P<seconds>\d+?)s)?')


def parse_time(time_str):
    parts = regex.match(time_str)
    if not parts:
        return
    parts = parts.groupdict()
    time_params = {}
    for name, param in parts.items():
        if param:
            time_params[name] = int(param)
    return timedelta(**time_params)


>>> from parse_time import parse_time
>>> parse_time('12hr')
datetime.timedelta(0, 43200)
>>> parse_time('12hr5m10s')
datetime.timedelta(0, 43510)
>>> parse_time('12hr10s')
datetime.timedelta(0, 43210)
>>> parse_time('10s')
datetime.timedelta(0, 10)
>>>
```

Comment: I was thinking of some kind of function that could take anything you throw at it and still be able to handle converting to timedelta.

Comment: I added re based solution example:)

Comment: I don't see how dateutil.parser.parse can parse durations, seems like it always returns a datetime. What am I missing?

Comment: `dateutil.parser.parse` won't parse `timedelta` objects. It returns a `datetime`, and it would trigger an exception for strings like `'28:32:11.10'`.

Answer (score 154):

To me the most elegant solution, without having to resort to external libraries such as [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil) or manually parsing the input, is to use [datetime's](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) powerful `strptime` string parsing method.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# we specify the input and the format...
t = datetime.strptime("05:20:25","%H:%M:%S")
# ...and use datetime's hour, min and sec properties to build a timedelta
delta = timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second)
```

After this you can use your timedelta object as normally, convert it to seconds to make sure we did the correct thing etc.

```
print(delta)
assert(5*60*60+20*60+25 == delta.total_seconds())
```

Comment: Note this approach only works if the timespan is less than 24 hours (`datetime.strptime("32:20:25","%H:%M:%S")` doesn't work), and you have to know the exact input format.

Comment: This also only part answers the OP's question. If the function needs to deal with multiple formats - you still need additional format inspection (1 colon or 2?).

Comment: In case days, months or years have to be used, it wouldn't be hard to expand on the format to e.g. "%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S". Details on the format options available in the [library docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior). In this case, though, it isn't quite clear to me what time delta is desired - seconds since O A.D.? Anyway, something in the manner of `delta = target_date - start_date` could be used to specify it.

Comment: @verdesmarald So, as of python 3.5, is there an elegant solution without using external libraries and without assuming timespan is less than 24 hours?

Comment: I find the need to manually specify the named parameters for the `timedelta` parameter pretty annoying, but the best I can come up with for avoiding this is: `delta = t - datetime.combine(t.date(), time.min)`, which is...horrible.

Comment: A serious problem with this approach is that if you include days then sending %d into strptime, will not enable you to input day 0, as only days of >=1 are valid for a date.

Comment: @metakermit Better not to use %Y (years) and %m (months) here, since they don't represent deterministic days.

Comment: Mention of `dateutil` is an unnecessary distraction. `dateutil.parse.parse` doesn't support timedelta objects.

Answer (score 120):

I had a bit of time on my hands yesterday, so I developed [@virhilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492048/virhilo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628148) into a Python module, adding a few more time expression formats, including all those requested by [@priestc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118495/priestc).

[Source code is on github](https://github.com/wroberts/pytimeparse) (MIT License) for anybody that wants it.  It's also on PyPI:

```
pip install pytimeparse
```

Returns the time as a number of seconds:

```
>>> from pytimeparse.timeparse import timeparse
>>> timeparse('32m')
1920
>>> timeparse('2h32m')
9120
>>> timeparse('4:13')
253
>>> timeparse('5hr34m56s')
20096
>>> timeparse('1.2 minutes')
72
```

Comment: is there a Java/Scala equivalent?

Comment: @luca.giovagnoli In Scala you can use Duration class. Duration can be constructed from strings like '15 seconds', '4 minutes' etc.

Answer (score 23):

If Pandas is already in your dependencies, it does this pretty well:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.Timedelta('5hr34m56s')
Timedelta('0 days 05:34:56')

>>> pd.Timedelta('2h32m')
Timedelta('0 days 02:32:00')

>>> pd.Timedelta('5hr34m56s')
Timedelta('0 days 05:34:56')

>>> # It is pretty forgiving:
>>> pd.Timedelta('2 days 24:30:00 10 sec')
Timedelta('3 days 00:30:10')
```

To convert to `datetime.timedelta` if you prefer that type:

```
>>> pd.Timedelta('1 days').to_pytimedelta()
datetime.timedelta(1)
```

Unfortunately this does not work though:

```
>>> pd.Timedelta('4:13')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.pyx", line 1217, in 
pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta.__new__
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timedeltas.pyx", line 454, in 
pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.parse_timedelta_string
ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format
```

Pandas actually has pretty extensive date and time tools even though that is not its main purpose.

To install Pandas:

```
# If you use pip
pip install pandas

# If you use conda
conda install pandas
```

Comment: If you are using pd can also use pd.to_timedelta

Answer (score 19):

I wanted to input just a time and then add it to various dates so this worked for me:

```
from datetime import datetime as dtt

time_only = dtt.strptime('15:30', "%H:%M") - dtt.strptime("00:00", "%H:%M")
```

Comment: `dtt.strptime(myduration, "%H:%M:%S") - dtt(1900, 1, 1)` also works...

Comment: got it. I wasn't sure dtt(1900,1,1) would work for every possible OS

Comment: best answer not requiring any external library or regex

Comment: For extracting timings out of a JSON dump, I used `duration = datetime.strptime(value, "%H:%M:%S.%f") - datetime.strptime("0", "%S")`. This is how Python saves these timedeltas to JSON (for durations less than one day, so typically anything like how a long a request took to process, etc).

Answer (score 19):

I've modified [virhilo's nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628148/851699) with a few upgrades:

- added a assertion that the string is a valid time string
- replace the "hr" hour-indicator with "h"
- allow for a "d" - days indicator
- allow non-integer times (e.g. `3m0.25s` is 3 minutes, 0.25 seconds)

.

```
import re
from datetime import timedelta


regex = re.compile(r'^((?P<days>[\.\d]+?)d)?((?P<hours>[\.\d]+?)h)?((?P<minutes>[\.\d]+?)m)?((?P<seconds>[\.\d]+?)s)?$')


def parse_time(time_str):
    """
    Parse a time string e.g. (2h13m) into a timedelta object.

    Modified from virhilo's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628148/851699

    :param time_str: A string identifying a duration.  (eg. 2h13m)
    :return datetime.timedelta: A datetime.timedelta object
    """
    parts = regex.match(time_str)
    assert parts is not None, "Could not parse any time information from '{}'.  Examples of valid strings: '8h', '2d8h5m20s', '2m4s'".format(time_str)
    time_params = {name: float(param) for name, param in parts.groupdict().items() if param}
    return timedelta(**time_params)
```

Comment: Great! I added " *" between the elements to also allow "1d 3h 5m"

Comment: @MarcelWaldvogel nice, if you copy the text of the new regex I'll add your answer in

Comment: @virhilo and Peter: My slight evolution on your code is here: https://github.com/zeitgitter/zeitgitterd/blob/master/zeitgitter/deltat.py . I presume it is OK to use your code. Do you have any preferences for the license? MIT, Apache, GPL, …?

Comment: Marcel, can you send me your address so I can sue?  JK go ahead any license is fine.

Comment: Here is the new Regex; the difference is the " *"s: regex = re.compile(r'^((?P<days>[\.\d]+?)d)? *'
                   r'((?P<hours>[\.\d]+?)h)? *'
                   r'((?P<minutes>[\.\d]+?)m)? *'
                   r'((?P<seconds>[\.\d]+?)s)?$')

Comment: In my copy of this function I also added the ability to make a negative time by starting the string with `'-'`.

Comment: The pattern `[\.\d]+` will match multiple `.`.  In fact, it will match a string with only `.`.

Answer (score 8):

Django comes with the utility function `parse_duration()`. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.dateparse.parse_duration):

> Parses a string and returns a `datetime.timedelta`.
>
> Expects data in the format `"DD HH:MM:SS.uuuuuu"` or as specified by ISO 8601 (e.g. `P4DT1H15M20S` which is equivalent to `4 1:15:20`) or PostgreSQL's day-time interval format (e.g. `3 days 04:05:06`).

Comment: For further information: Django's `parse_duration()` function uses regex match under the hood.

Answer (score 7):

Use [isodate](https://pypi.org/project/isodate/) library to parse ISO 8601 duration string. For example:

```
isodate.parse_duration('PT1H5M26S')
```

Also see [Is there an easy way to convert ISO 8601 duration to timedelta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976138/is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-iso-8601-duration-to-timedelta)

Answer (score 7):

if you want to use : as separator, I use this function:

```
import re
from datetime import timedelta

def timedelta_parse(value):
    """
    convert input string to timedelta
    """
    value = re.sub(r"[^0-9:.]", "", value)
    if not value:
        return

    return timedelta(**{key:float(val)
                        for val, key in zip(value.split(":")[::-1], 
                                            ("seconds", "minutes", "hours", "days"))
               })
```

Examples:

```
In [4]: timedelta_parse("1:0:0:1")
Out[4]: datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=1)

In [5]: timedelta_parse("123.5")
Out[5]: datetime.timedelta(seconds=123, microseconds=500000)

In [6]: timedelta_parse("1:6:34:9.983")
Out[6]: datetime.timedelta(days=1, seconds=23649, microseconds=983000)

In [8]: timedelta_parse("23:45:00")
Out[8]: datetime.timedelta(seconds=85500)
```

Comment: It don't process  microseconds after point

Comment: You were right: re.sub should leave dots in the string. I corrected the function, it should work now. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you use Python 3 then here's updated version for Hari Shankar's solution, which I used:

```
from datetime import timedelta
import re

regex = re.compile(r'(?P<hours>\d+?)/'
                   r'(?P<minutes>\d+?)/'
                   r'(?P<seconds>\d+?)$')

def parse_time(time_str):
    parts = regex.match(time_str)
    if not parts:
        return
    parts = parts.groupdict()
    print(parts)
    time_params = {}
    for name, param in parts.items():
        if param:
            time_params[name] = int(param)
    return timedelta(**time_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying [tempora.parse_timedelta](https://tempora.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#tempora.parse_timedelta) (from [tempora](https://pypi.org/project/tempora)).

```
$ pip-run 'tempora>=4.1.1' -- -q
>>> from tempora import parse_timedelta
>>> parse_timedelta("32m")
datetime.timedelta(seconds=1920)
>>> parse_timedelta("2h32m")
datetime.timedelta(seconds=9120)
>>> parse_timedelta("4:13")
datetime.timedelta(seconds=15180)
>>> parse_timedelta("5hr34m56s")
datetime.timedelta(seconds=20096)
```

Comment: Consider adding a link to a download somewhere?  Maybe a PyPI page?  I assume it exists, but I can't tell from your "answer".

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard Done. I thought it was obvious from `pip-run 'tempora>=4.1.1'`, but I realize many wouldn't know pip-run or know that it accepts the same syntax as `pip install`. I also filed [jaraco/skeleton#77](https://github.com/jaraco/skeleton/issues/77) to consider addressing the general deficiency (docs don't link easily to the project).

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from datetime import timedelta

class InvalidTimeString(Exception):
    """Exception raised when the input string is not a valid time string."""

_TIME_REGEX = re.compile(r'((?P<hours>\d+?)hr)|((?P<minutes>\d+?)m)|((?P<seconds>\d+?)s)')

def parse_time(time_str: str) -> timedelta | None:
    """
    Parse a time string into a timedelta object.

    Args:
        time_str (str): The time string to parse. This can include hours ("Xhr"), minutes ("Ym"), and seconds ("Zs").
            Each component is optional and can appear in any order, but they should be separated by non-numeric characters.

    Returns:
        timedelta: A timedelta object representing the time in the input string.

    Raises:
        InvalidTimeString: If the input string is not a valid time string.

    Usage:
    >>> parse_time('12hr5m10s')
    datetime.timedelta(seconds=43510)
    >>> parse_time('12hr')
    datetime.timedelta(seconds=43200)
    >>> parse_time('12hr10s')
    datetime.timedelta(seconds=43210)
    >>> parse_time('12hr5m10s')
    datetime.timedelta(seconds=43510)
    >>> parse_time('5m10s12hr')
    datetime.timedelta(seconds=43510)
    """
    time_params = {"hours": 0, "minutes": 0, "seconds": 0}
    matches = _TIME_REGEX.finditer(time_str)
    if not matches:
        raise InvalidTimeString(f"'{time_str}' is not a valid time string")

    for match in matches:
        match_dict = match.groupdict()
        for name, param in match_dict.items():
            if param:
                time_params[name] = int(param)

    return timedelta(**time_params)
```

The `parse_time` function is designed to parse a time string into a Python timedelta object. The input time string can include hours ("Xhr"), minutes ("Ym"), and seconds ("Zs") in any order. Each component is optional and can be separated by non-numeric characters.

The function begins by defining a regular expression that is capable of matching these time string components. This regular expression includes named groups for hours, minutes, and seconds, which makes it easier to extract these values later.

Next, the function uses the finditer method of the regular expression to find all matches in the input string. This method returns an iterator yielding match objects for every non-overlapping match of the regular expression pattern in the string.

The function then iterates over each match, converting the match object into a dictionary using the groupdict method. This method returns a dictionary containing all the named groups found in the match, with the group names as the keys and the matched strings as the values.

For each named group in the dictionary, the function checks if the group has a value. If it does, the function converts this value into an integer and stores it in the time_params dictionary under the appropriate key (hours, minutes, or seconds).

Finally, the function creates a `timedelta` object from the time_params dictionary and returns it.

There are several advantages to using this approach:

1. **Flexibility**: The function can handle time strings in a variety of formats, making it more useful in different situations.
2. **Robustness**: The function includes error checking to ensure that the input string is a valid time string. If it is not, the function raises a custom exception to indicate this.
3. **Readability**: The use of regular expressions and named groups makes the code more readable and easier to understand.
4. **Efficiency**: By using a dictionary to store the time components and a timedelta object to represent the final result, the function can handle the time calculations more efficiently.