# Parse time string in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to construct a timedelta object from a simple string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628122/how-to-construct-a-timedelta-object-from-a-simple-string)

I have a string that is in the format `hours:minutes:seconds` but it is not a time of day but a duration. For example, `100:00:00` means `100 hours`.

I am trying to find the time that is offset from the current time by the amount of time specified in the string. I could use regular expressions to manually pull apart the time string and convert it to seconds and add it to the floating point returned by `time.time()`, but is there a `time` function to do this?

The `time.strptime()` function formatting seems to work on time of day/date strings and not arbitrary strings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628122/how-to-construct-a-timedelta-object-from-a-simple-string

Comment: Looks good, I couldn't find that one. Thanks!

Comment: timedelta should be useful here.

Comment: This question is different from the duplicate, this one has a clear input (hh:mm:ss) and output in seconds, the other one has less common formats as input and timedelta as output.

Answer (score 7):

```
import datetime
dur_str = "100:00:00"
h, m, s = map(int, dur_str.split(':'))
dur = datetime.timedelta(hours=h, minutes=m, seconds=s)
```

Comment: nice! forgot you can pass the hours, minutes, seconds values directly.

Comment: This won't work for shorter formats like 'mm:ss', though..

Comment: To quote the asker, "I have a string that is in the format `hours:minutes:seconds`..."

It's actually really easy to make this handle short formats; just condition on the number of elements from the `.split(':')`.

Answer (score 1):

not using `re` but sometimes it's more work to understand the regex than write the python.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> time_str = "100:00:00"
>>> hours, minutes, seconds = [int(i) for i in time_str.split(":")]
>>> time_in_seconds = hours * 60 * 60 + minutes * 60 + seconds
>>> time_in_seconds
360000
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> now
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 2, 10, 24, 6, 639000)
>>> new_time = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=time_in_seconds)
>>> new_time
datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 6, 14, 24, 6, 639000)
```

As nneonneo pointed out `datetime.timedelta()` accepts the `hours`, `minutes`, and `seconds` as arguments.  So you can even do something silly like this (not recommended):

```
>>> datetime.timedelta(**{k:v for k,v in zip(["hours", "minutes", "seconds"], [int(i) for i in "100:00:00".split(":")])})
datetime.timedelta(4, 14400)
```