# How should I be accepting time durations in query string?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, time

I have a small REST API with Python and Flask, and for some GET requests I need to accept a look-behind time duration parameter, e.g. "A months, B days, C hours, D minutes".

This parameter will be parsed from a query string, but I'm a bit unsure how I should be structuring my query string for parsing. There are other fields in the query string besides the look-behind, which complicates things a bit.

There are two main options I have come up with.

1. Accept a single field for the look-behind in the query string, e.g. `"8months5days"`, then extend  some regex solution like [virhilo's here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628148/5636510) for the string passed:

   ```
   regex = re.compile(r'((?P<hours>\d+?)hr)?((?P<minutes>\d+?)m)?((?P<seconds>\d+?)s)?')
   ```

   after which I can construct a `datetime.timedelta` from the result.
2. Accept several fields for different components of a time duration in my query string, e.g. `"behind_m=8&behind_d=5"`. Then use `urllib` to get a dictionary of the full query string,

   ```
   query_d = parse_qs(request.query_string)
   ```

   and finally take the intersection of `query_d` with a dictionary like

   ```
   durations = {'behind_m': 'months', 'behind_d': 'days', 'behind_y': 'years', ...}
   ```

   after which I can directly construct a `datetime.timedelta`.

My natural inclination is to go for the second option, since I am weak with regex and I like the clarity. However, I could end up requiring *multiple* time durations in some query strings, which will result in enormously long query strings in some cases.

**Is there a good way to accomplish this, and is that way regex**? I understand that the entire task would be much simpler if there was a clean way to parse a time duration from some string format, but despite looking at [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) and [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) I haven't found any support for duration parsing.

Comment: I would use purely seconds and drop the other units. You could then use relative seconds or seconds since epoch

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Yeahh I agree actually, this makes sense. I haven't really implemented a front-end framework to communicate with the API yet and so had myself sort of fixed on having query strings someone could easily provide themselves, so that's why that didn't cross my mind. But it is sensible I think. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My tool of choice would be a comma separated list in the URI:

```
?behind=2,1,20,1,23,3
```

Resolving to:

```
durations = {'years': 2, 'months': 1, 'days': 20, hours: 1, minutes: 23, seconds: 3}
```

Based on the common use case (if you are entering more longer durations or short ones) I'd decide either to go for the format `year,months,days,hours,minutes,seconds` or the reverse.

To build this `dict` you can `split`the string and put it into the dict:

```
identifiers = ['years', 'months', 'days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']
components = behind.split(str=",")
duration = dict(zip(identifiers, components))
```