# Convert string timedelta into python datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta, python-datetime

I have a string that represents the timedelta in the format `X days HH:MM:SS`.

Eg :

```
0 days 00:10:07
1 days 00:01:02
```

I want to convert it to

1. python **`datetime.timedelta`** format.
2. Minutes (i.e in above example it would say 10 mins and second example 1 day*60*24+1 hour *60 = 1500)

Can I use `strptime`  method to parse it and convert to correct format? If not that, is there a way **without** using reg-ex `re` module ?

**Edit :**

- A similar question on stack-overflow explains the usage of `strptime`
  method. However it assumes that the input is a specific `datetime`.
- In my case, the interval is given as a `timedelta` but in string
  format.
- The top voted answer uses the **regex** - I prefer to use the    inbuilt
  datetime library to parse unless it cannot be done without    regex

Comment: the answer on this post answers it nicely. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628122/how-to-construct-a-timedelta-object-from-a-simple-string

Comment: @NickBrady I hope the edit is able to to explain why this is not a duplicate question.

Comment: Hi @Spandan, I'm sorry for not reading the question thoroughly enough.. I must have missed that. Looking at the docs https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior it seems to say pretty explicitly that the `.strptime` method isn't available for timedelta objects, though I don't personally know if there is an alternative method. Given the other answer is the highest voted it is _likely_ the best method for doing what you want, but perhaps not. I'm not leaving this as an answer in the hopes someone better helps you, or you post the answer you find yourself :).