# datetime conversion ValueError Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset with wrong times (24:00:00 to 26:18:00) I wanted to know what is the best approach to deal with this kind of data in python.

I tried to convert the column from object to `datetime` using this code:

```
stopTimeArrDep['departure_time'] =  pd.to_datetime(stopTimeArrDep['departure_time']\
                                                   ,format='%H:%M:%S')
```

But I get this error:

```
ValueError: time data '24:04:00' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)
```

So I tried adding `errors='coerce'` to avoid this error. But I end up with empty columns and unwanted date added to every row.

```
stopTimeArrDep['departure_time'] =  pd.to_datetime(stopTimeArrDep['departure_time']\
                                                   ,format='%H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')
```

output sample:

```
original_col    converted_col
23:45:00        1/1/00 23:45:00
23:51:00        1/1/00 23:51:00
24:04:00
23:42:00        1/1/00 23:42:00
26:01:00
```

Any suggestion on what is the best approach to handle this issue. Thank you,

Comment: The reason you are getting error is because the `H` value you have is more than 23:59:59 (a day has only 24 hours). Those values cannot be 'coerced' either. If you a have date along-with time, you can bump up the date to next day & hours could start from 0 after 24 has been reached.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I only have times.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You could treat the `original_col` as some elapsed time interval and not time, if that makes any sense. You could use `datetime.timedelta` and then add this `datetime.timedelta` to a `datetime.datetime` to get some datetime object; which you could finally use to get the date and time separately.

### Example

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time_string = "20:30:20"

t = datetime.utcnow()
print('t: {}'.format(t))
HH, MM, SS = [int(x) for x in time_string.split(':')]
dt = timedelta(hours=HH, minutes=MM, seconds=SS)
print('dt: {}'.format(dt))
t2 = t + dt
print('t2: {}'.format(t2))
print('t2.date: {} | t2.time: {}'.format(str(t2.date()), str(t2.time()).split('.')[0]))
```

**Output**:

```
t: 2019-10-24 04:43:08.255027
dt: 20:30:20
t2: 2019-10-25 01:13:28.255027
t2.date: 2019-10-25 | t2.time: 01:13:28
```

> ## For Your Usecase

```py
# Define Custom Function
def process_row(time_string):
    HH, MM, SS = [int(x) for x in time_string.split(':')]
    dt = timedelta(hours=HH, minutes=MM, seconds=SS)
    return dt

# Make Dummy Data
original_col = ["23:45:00", "23:51:00", "24:04:00", "23:42:00", "26:01:00"]
df = pd.DataFrame({'original_col': original_col, 'dt': None})

# Process Dataframe
df['dt'] = df.apply(lambda x: process_row(x['original_col']), axis=1)
df['t'] = datetime.utcnow()
df['t2'] = df['dt'] + df['t']
# extracting date from timestamp
df['Date'] = [datetime.date(d) for d in df['t2']] 
# extracting time from timestamp
df['Time'] = [datetime.time(d) for d in df['t2']] 
df
```

**Output**:
[image]

### Using `pandas.to_datetime()`:

```py
pd.to_datetime(df['t2'], format='%H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')
```

**Output**:

```
0   2019-10-25 09:38:39.349410
1   2019-10-25 09:44:39.349410
2   2019-10-25 09:57:39.349410
3   2019-10-25 09:35:39.349410
4   2019-10-25 11:54:39.349410
Name: t2, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

## References

1. [How to construct a timedelta object from a simple string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628122/how-to-construct-a-timedelta-object-from-a-simple-string)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am not sure how to reflect this to my dataframe column. Could you clarify it to me. Thanks

Comment: Well, if you consider a single row in `original_col`, what I mentioned above, could be applied to that. So, you could make a custom function where you just pass in the `time_string` and some datetime (as reference: this will replace `t`) and out comes t2. This could by applied to each row and that could be finally stored in a new column. You would need to use `pandas.Series.apply` for this purpose.

Comment: I will add some more stuff for more clarity.

Comment: @leena See the section: **For Your Usecase** for an example.

Comment: Thank you CypherX. But time column is still an `object` not `datetime`.

Comment: And returns few errors when I replace `df` with my dataframe name. And `original_column` with the column name. Such as: `KeyError: ('departure_time', 'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: @leena The solution that I provided with the data, please confirm if that is reproducible or not. Since I do not have access to your actual data, I would not be able to diagnose/fix the errors you are getting. Here `t2` is the `datetime`. You will have to use the ideas shared here to adapt to your specific usecase.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201374/discussion-between-cypherx-and-leena).