# Parse string like "15 mins" or "1hr 10mins" to seconds

Tags: python-3.x

Does anyone know where I can find a good function that converts a string like "15 mins" or "1hr 20mins" into an integer denoting the number of seconds?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to construct a timedelta object from a simple string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628122/how-to-construct-a-timedelta-object-from-a-simple-string)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find your solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628122/how-to-construct-a-timedelta-object-from-a-simple-string) , and you can write your own function which does this, by writing a formal way to parse your time, you can transform your string into a datetime and the rest is straight forward.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# we specify the input and the format...
t = datetime.strptime("05:20:25","%H:%M:%S")
# ...and use datetime's hour, min and sec properties to build a timedelta
delta = timedelta(hours=t.hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second)
print(delta)
assert(5*60*60+20*60+25 == delta.total_seconds())
```