# Get highest duration from a list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of durations like below

```
['5d', '20h', '1h', '7m', '14d', '1m']
```

where `d` stands for days, `h` stands for hours and `m` stands for minutes.

I want to get the highest duration from this list(`14d` in this case). How can I get that from this list of strings?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4628148/1224467 This answer has a solution to turn your strings into timedeltas. These can be sorted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pure python solution. We could store mapping between our time extensions (`m`, `h`, `d`) and minutes (here `time_map`), to find highest duration. Here we're using `max()` with `key` argument to apply our mapping.

```py
inp = ['5d', '20h', '1h', '7m', '14d', '1m']
time_map = {'m': 1, 'h': 60, 'd': 24*60}

print(max(inp, key=lambda x:int(x[:-1])*time_map[x[-1]]))  # -> 14d
```

Answer (score 15):

`np.argmax` on `pd.to_timedelta`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

durations = ['5d', '20h', '1h', '7m', '14d', '1m']

durations[np.argmax(pd.to_timedelta(durations))]
```

```
Out[24]: '14d'
```

`pd.to_timedelta` turns a string into a duration ([source](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timedelta.html)), and `np.argmax` returns the index of the highest element.

Comment: Although I am not going to use numpy and/or pandas for the project I am having this issue, but I must say that's an amazing example of using library functions efficiently to get your job done.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an absolute hack which solves the problem in a bad but clever way: Python's `min` and `max` functions can be used with a `key` function which is used to compare elements, so that it returns the element minimising or maximising that function. If the `key` function returns a tuple, then the order is determined by the first component of the tuple, using the second component as a tie-breaker.

We can exploit the fact that the last characters `'d'`, `'h'` and `'m'` can be compared in alphabetical order; a **d**ay is longer than an **h**our is longer than a **m**inute. This means the longest duration has the *minimum* character in alphabetical order, with the *maximum* integer as a tie-breaker. Maximising that integer is the same as minimising its negation:

```py
>>> durations = ['5d', '20h', '1h', '7m', '14d', '1m']
>>> min(durations, key=lambda d: (d[-1], -int(d[:-1])))
'14d'
```

Comment: You could have seconds represented as `s`, and weeks as `W` and months as `M`, and it would still work; the hack breaks if you include years as either `y` or `Y`, though. It also relies on there not being any durations like `10000000m` where a larger unit could be used instead; I'm assuming the strings are the output of some API which always uses the largest unit possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = ['5d', '20h', '1h', '7m', '14d', '1m']
max(lst, key=lambda s: (-ord(s[-1]), int(s[:-1])))
```

Output:

```
'14d'
```

Useful for this particular set of strings, but if the format differs, will need to adjust the first element of the tuple accordingly.  Right now it makes sense because `s` > `m` > `h` > `d`.

Answer (score 3):

here is a solution with regular expression

```py
import numpy as np
import re

new_list = []
x=['5d', '20h', '1h', '7m', '14d', '1m']
map_time={"d":1440, "h":60, "m":1}

for item in x:
    letter=re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+",item)
    number=re.findall("[1-9]+",item)
    new_list.append(map_time[letter[0]]*int(number[0]))

x[np.argmax(new_list)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Provided that your times are well-formed, you can find the `max` based on a single regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> durations = ['5d', '20h', '1h', '7m', '14d', '1m']
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(?:(\d*)d)?(?:(\d*)h)?(?:(\d*)m)?')
>>> max(inp, key=lambda tme: tuple(map(int, pattern.match(tme).groups(default=0))))
'14d'
```

The regular expression creates a tuple of days, hours, minutes as strings. The `tuple(map(int, ...))` converts it to integers. `max` picks the largest of these tuples, which naturally weight days stronger than hours stringer than minutes.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way :

```py
duration = ['5d', '20h', '1h', '7m', '14d', '1m', '2d']
duration_std = [0]*len(duration)

equivalence = {"d":60*60*24, "h":60*60, "m":60}

for idx, val in enumerate(duration):
    duration_std[idx] = int(val[:-1])*equivalence[val[-1]]

print(duration[duration_std.index(max(duration_std))])
```

Output

```py
"14d"
```