# Dataframe - mean of string type column with time values

Tags: python, dataframe, time

I have to calculate mean() of time column, but this column type is string, how can I do it?

```
id   time
1   1h:2m
2   1h:58m
3    35m
4    2h
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regex to extract hours and minutes. To calcualte the mean time in minutus:

```
h = df['time'].str.extract('(\d{1,2})h').fillna(0).astype(int)
m = df['time'].str.extract('(\d{1,2})m').fillna(0).astype(int)

(h * 60 + m).mean()
```

Result:

```
0    83.75
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

It's largely inspired from [How to construct a timedelta object from a simple string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4628122/12744275), but you can do as below:

```
def convertToSecond(time_str):
    regex=re.compile(r'((?P<hours>\d+?)h)?:*((?P<minutes>\d+?)m)?:*((?P<seconds>\d+?)s)?')
    parts = regex.match(time_str)
    if not parts:
        return

    parts = parts.groupdict()
    time_params = {}
    for (name, param) in parts.items():
        if param:
            time_params[name] = int(param)
    return timedelta(**time_params).total_seconds()

df = pd.DataFrame({
'time': ['1h:2m', '1h:58m','35m','2h'],})


df['inSecond']=df['time'].apply(convertToSecond)
mean_inSecond=df['inSecond'].mean()
print(f"Mean of Time Column: {datetime.timedelta(seconds=mean_inSecond)}")
```

Result:

```
Mean of Time Column: 1:23:45
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to convert your string column into `timedelta` (since they don't seem to be times but rather durations?).

Since your strings are not all formatted equally, you unfortinately cannot use pandas' `to_timedelta` function. However, `parser` from `dateutil` has an option `fuzzy` that you can use to convert your column to `datetime`. If you subtract midnight today from that, you get the value as a `timedelta`.

```
import pandas as pd 
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'1h:2m'],[2,'1h:58m'],[3,'35m'],[4,'2h']],columns=['id','time'])

today = date.today()
midnight = datetime.combine(today, datetime.min.time())

df['time'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: (parser.parse(x, fuzzy=True)) - midnight)
```

This will convert your dataframe like this (`print(df)`):

```
   id     time
0   1 01:02:00
1   2 01:58:00
2   3 00:35:00
3   4 02:00:00
```

from which you can calculate the mean using `print(df['time'].mean())`:

```
0 days 01:23:45
```

Full example: https://ideone.com/Aze9mR