# Convert string to dateTime without the date information Python

Tags: python, string, list, datetime, type-conversion

I am trying to convert the following list of strings :

```
['0:00:01.138000', '0:00:03.733000', '0:00:01.250000', '0:00:01.127000']
```

But when I try the following code :

```
T = '%H:%M:%S.%f'

for i in range(len(Normal_key)):
    try:
        Normal_key[i]=datetime.strptime(Normal_key[i], T)
    except ValueError:
        continue

print(Normal_key)
```

The list now contains data information for some reason even though no date was specified:

```
[datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 138000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 733000), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 250000)]
```

Comment: That's just a default date added; you could use `datetime.strptime(Normal_key[i], T).time()` to strip the date

Comment: It still returns the same exact format.

Comment: You should now have time objects instead of datetime objects. What "*format*" do you expect exactly?

Comment: I wanted to get the milliseconds and for that the following worked: (datetime.strptime(Normal_key[i], T).time().microsecond/1000))

Comment: ok so what you're actually dealing with are duration (`timedelta` in Python). Note that the `datetime.strptime` method will fail if for example the hour exceeds 23. You might want to have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4628122/10197418) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you are using datetime module so it is by default adding the starting date to it. you can extract just the time using

```
datetime.strptime("0:00:01.138000", "%H:%M:%S.%f").time()
```

Comment: It works if i do this: (datetime.strptime(Normal_key[i], T).time().microsecond/1000) and convert it from microseconds to milliseconds .