# How to parse 10m10s to 10 minutes and 10 seconds in Python

Tags: python

So basically, I have a question which has already bothering me for time. What I am trying to do is parse the time like `10m10s` or `5d6w` like that, into 10 minutes and 10 seconds, 6 weeks and 5 days (or 1 month, 2 weeks and 5 days) accordingly. Is there a fast way or nice solution for it?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: See here as a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime

Comment: Here's some approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628122/how-to-construct-a-timedelta-object-from-a-simple-string

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the format is always `<number><identifier>` with identifiers as

```
d   # day
s   # second
µs  # microsecond
ms  # millisecond
m   # minute
h   # hour
w   # week
```

You could use a regex coupled with `datetime.timedelta`:

```
import re
from datetime import timedelta

s1 = '10m10s1d1w1d8ms'

# extract the parameters in order of `timedelta`
reg = re.compile(r'(\d+)d|(\d+)s|(\d+)µs|(\d+)ms|(\d+)m|(\d+)h|(\d+)w')

# sum the identical units to form a single list
params = [sum(int(e) for e in t if e) for t in zip(*reg.findall(s1))]

# create a timedelta object
t = timedelta(*params)
```

output:

```
datetime.timedelta(days=9, seconds=610, microseconds=8000)
```

*NB. The order of the parameters of timedelta is:*

```
timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)
```

###### as a function

```
def str_to_tdelta(s):
    import re
    from datetime import timedelta
    reg = re.compile(r'(\d+)d|(\d+)s|(\d+)µs|(\d+)ms|(\d+)m|(\d+)h|(\d+)w')
    params = [sum(int(e) for e in t if e) for t in zip(*reg.findall(s))]
    return timedelta(*params)


str_to_tdelta('5d6w')
# datetime.timedelta(days=47)
```