# Convert date with more than 31 days to regular date format in python

Tags: python, datetime, time, format

I have exported some data from another programm, where I added up time for a station waiting.
So after some time, I have the format '32:00:00:33.7317' for the waiting time.

This is my function to convert every date into the format I want:

```
def Datum_formatieren(Datensatz):
    if len(str(Datensatz)) == 24:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(Datensatz, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f").strftime("%d%H%M")
    elif len(str(Datensatz)) == 3:
        return 0
        #return datetime.datetime.strptime(Datensatz, "%S.%f").strftime("%d%H%M")
    elif len(str(Datensatz)) == 5:
        return str(Datensatz)
    elif len(str(Datensatz)) == 7:
        return str(Datensatz)
    elif len(str(Datensatz)) == 6:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(str(Datensatz), "%S.%f").strftime("%d%H%M")
    elif len(str(Datensatz)) == 9 or len(str(Datensatz))==10:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(str(Datensatz), "%M:%S.%f").strftime("%d%H%M")
    elif len(str(Datensatz)) == 12 or len(str(Datensatz)) ==13:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(str(Datensatz), "%H:%M:%S.%f").strftime("%d%H%M")
    elif len(str(Datensatz)) == 15 or len(str(Datensatz)) == 16:
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(str(Datensatz), "%d:%H:%M:%S.%f").strftime("%d%H%M")
```

I get the following error since python does not recognize days above 30 or 31:

```
ValueError: time data '32:00:00:33.7317' does not match format '%d:%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

How do I convert all entries with days above 31 into a format, which python can recognize?

Comment: Why are you using `str()` on `Datensatz`? It's almost always an error to use `str()` and then parse the result. Can you try skipping the `str()` and formatting the value directly from `Datensatz`?

Comment: Because I need to know the length of the date i want to convert into the needed format. The formats are always different depending on the length of the entry

Comment: You should be able to get that directly from `Datensatz`; what type is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `datetime.datetime.strptime()` to construct datetimes that are invalid - why see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71524074/7505395).

You can however leverage `datetime.timespan`:

```
import datetime 

def Datum_formatieren(Datensatz):        
    # other cases omitted for brevity

    # Input:  "days:hours:minutes:seconds.ms"
    if len(Datensatz) in (15,16):
        k = list(map(float,Datensatz.split(":")))
        secs = k[0]*60*60*24 + k[1]*60*60 + k[2]*60 + k[3]  
        td = datetime.timedelta(seconds=secs)
        days = td.total_seconds() / 24 / 60 // 60
        hours = (td.total_seconds() - days * 24*60*60) / 60 // 60
        minuts = (td.total_seconds() - days *24*60*60 - hours * 60*60) // 60
        print(td)
        return f"{td.days}{int(hours):02d}{int(minuts):02d}"

print(Datum_formatieren("32:32:74:33.731"))
```

Output for `"32:32:74:33.731"`:

```
33 days, 9:14:33.731000   # timespan
330914                    # manually parsed
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misusing [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) wich only map to correct dates with times - not "any amount time passed".

Use a `timedelta` instead:

Adapted from [datetime.timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

> ```
> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
> delta = timedelta( days=50, seconds=27, microseconds=10, 
>                    milliseconds=29000, minutes=5, hours=8, weeks=2 )
>
> print(datetime.now() + delta)
> ```

You can add any timedelta to a normal datetime and get the resulting value.

---

If you want to stick wich your approach you may want to shorten it:

> ```
>  if len(str(Datensatz)) == 9 or len(str(Datensatz))==10:
> ```

```
 if len(Datensatz) in (9,10):
```

---

Related: [How to construct a timedelta object from a simple string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628122/how-to-construct-a-timedelta-object-from-a-simple-string) (look at its answers and take inspiration with attribution from it)

Comment: Looking at the code in thequestion, it's quite possible `Datensatz` is already `timedelta`

Comment: @JiříBaum Datensatz is a string that is parsed via `datetime.datetime.strptime()` wich leads to a DateTime. That is then formatted back into a string.  You cannot have a "DateTime" with a dayvalue of 32 - that is the problem here.

Comment: The code works so far, the only problem I have is that i get an error, if the %d is above 31 as python does not recognize days above 31

Comment: @Tarik - DateTime - Objects describe a DATE.  `datetime.datetime.strptime()` returns a DateTime.  Give me one calenderial Date that has a dayvalue of 32.    This will also crash for *all invalid dates*:  Februar has only 28 or 29 days  depending on the year - try to create a string of length 24 `Datensatz = "30.02.2022 10:10:10.4444" ` and feed it into your function.

Comment: Yes, I get what you are saying, but I need these values in the format that they are counting the days, so could i somehow convert each entry, which has days > 31 into month:1 and days:0
So "32:00:00:33.7317" becomes "01:00:00:00:33.7317"

Comment: @PatrickArtner - it looks like `Datensatz` is _not_ a string; the code always uses it as `str(Datensatz)` so it looks like it's originally a different type. That type probably has direct access to the number of days, hours, minutes, seconds etc.

Comment: @JiříBaum  ...  _   '32:00:00:33.7317' _  is a string - thats directly from the question. And  you can do `str(str(str(str("of this string"))))` all day long .... and still feed it a string. The code uses `datetime.datetime.strptime(Datensatz, "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")`  without str as well - the str is only needlessly used for len() measurement.

Comment: Sure; I have a hunch `Datensatz` is not a string, though

Answer (score 0):

- You're taking the `Datensatz` variable, converting it to string using `str()`, then parsing it back into an internal representation; there is almost always a better way to do it.

  Can you check what type the `Datensatz` variable has, perhaps `print(type(Datensatz))` or based on the rest of your code?

  Most likely the `Datensatz` variable already has fields for the number of days, hours, minutes and seconds. It's usually much better to base your logic on those directly, rather than converting to string and back.
- As others have pointed out, you're trying to use a `datetime.datetime` to represent a time interval; this is incorrect. Instead, you need to either:

  - Use the `datetime.timedelta` type, which is designed for time intervals. It can handle periods over 30 days correctly:

    ```
    >>> print(datetime.timedelta(days=32, seconds=12345))
    32 days, 3:25:45
    >>>
    ```
  - Since your function is named `Datum_formatieren`, perhaps you intend to take `Datensatz` and convert it to string, for output to the user or to another system.

    In that case, you should take the fields directly in `Datensatz` and convert them appropriately, perhaps using f-strings or % formatting. Depending on the situation, you may need to do some arithmetic. The details will depend on the type of `Datensatz` and the format you need on the output.