# Convert integer in format HHMMSS to datetime in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a long dataframe (35 million rows) of data that includes a Time column. The time in the original CSV is in the format HHMMSS, which translates into pandas as an integer. Being an integer, if the Hours are less than 2 digits the first digit drops off (ex: 090000 (9am) becomes 90000 in pandas).

I am trying to convert these integers into an actual datetime value that I can extract `.time()` from, so as to be able to count in custom intervals of minutes, seconds, hours etc.

How do I convert an integer (such as 90000 or 100000) into their respective times (9am, 10am)?

Comment: Are you using `read_csv` ? You can use `parse_dates` to specify the column should be parsed as a date

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I am, could you share the syntax for that ?

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_datetime` after converting to string and `zfill`ing the zeros:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': [90000, 0, 123456]})

df['time2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str).str.zfill(6), format='%H%M%S').dt.time
```

Or, as string:

```
df['time2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype(str).str.zfill(6), format='%H%M%S').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
     time     time2
0   90000  09:00:00
1       0  00:00:00
2  123456  12:34:56
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the values to time (Timedelta) directly when loading through the `converters` parameter. This parameter tells `read_csv` how to convert specific columns. Unfortunately, there's no equivalent to `strptime` for timedelta.

One quick & dirty way to parse this format into a timedelta is to [use a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628122/how-to-construct-a-timedelta-object-from-a-simple-string) or just split the string into parts, eg :

```
def parse_timedelta(time_str):
    s=time_str.zfill(6)
    return pd.Timedelta(
        hours=int(s[0:2]),
        minutes=int(s[2:4]),
        seconds=int(s[4:6]))
```

This can be used to convert fields in `HHMMSS` format to timedelta:

```
csv="Time\n90000\n000000\n123456"
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv),converters={'Time':parse_time})
>>> df
             Time
0 3 days 18:00:00
1 0 days 00:00:00
2 0 days 12:34:56
```