# How can I print a day and a time using Python strftime?

Tags: python, python-datetime, valueerror, strptime, strftime

**Context:**
I'm trying to format a day and time using Python's strftime function, but I'm encountering a "ValueError." I want the output to be in the format "1 day, 2:45:00" to represent a valid datetime object. However, my current code is throwing the following error: "ValueError: time data '1 day, 2:45:00' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'."
.

```
from datetime import datetime


actualTime = '1 day, 2:45:00'
strpTime = datetime.strptime(f"{actualTime}", "%H:%M:%S")
fomtTime = strpTime.strftime("%I:%M %p")
print(fomtTime)
```

**Issue:**
I would like to know how to format a day and time in the desired format ("1 day, 2:45:00") using Python's strftime function without encountering a ValueError. I appreciate any insights or corrections to my code.

Thank you.

Comment: The immediate problem is that you're asking Python to parse your string with a format of `hour:minutes:seconds`, but your sting also includes `"1 day, "`. Perhaps more importantly, what kind of date is "1 day"? How do you *want* that interpreted?

Comment: I want the output to be **1 day, 2:45:00**, so that it can be a valid datetime object.

Comment: Because I want to format it with strftime. And I believe that cannot be done if it is not a valid datetime object.

Comment: It looks more a `timedelta` than a `datetime`

Comment: @norok2, sure, but `timedelta` has not `strptime`, and you can make `datetime.strptime` work, [usually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628122/how-to-construct-a-timedelta-object-from-a-simple-string)

Comment: @Him so how do I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'%d day, %H:%M:%S'
```

You can use this format instead.

Comment: actualTime = '1 day, 2:45:00'
strpTime = datetime.strptime(f"{actualTime}", '%d day, %H:%M:%S')
fomtTime = strpTime.strftime("%I:%M %p")
print(fomtTime)