# How I can compare the length of song time?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to compare the length of song tme to find what song in my play list is the longest and print his name. I got a list with all the times, for example I got the list `['5:13', '4:05', '4:15', '4:23', '4:13']` and now I need to compare the times but I have no idea how to convert the str list to int list and compare the times. Any suggetions?

Comment: How do you store song names?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628122/how-to-construct-a-timedelta-object-from-a-simple-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) provides a way to use a key function to convert each item in the list.

```
def seconds(x):
  m, s = x.split(':')
  return int(m) * 60 + int(s)

durations = ['5:13', '4:05', '4:15', '4:23', '4:13']
m = max(durations, key=seconds)
print(m) # will print '5:13'
```

Answer (score 1):

Short and painless:

```py
durations=['5:13', '4:05', '4:15', '4:23', '4:13', '11:05']
print(sorted(durations, key=lambda x: tuple(map(int, x.split(":")))))
```

### Output

```
['4:05', '4:13', '4:15', '4:23', '5:13', '11:05']
```